# Can I install a new dimmer on existing aluminum wiring?

Tags: wiring, aluminum-wiring

I have aluminum wiring. Can I install a dimmer switch in place of a standard toggle switch and also standard on/off switches without the ground wire?

Comment: The dimmer must be listed as AL/CU and you must obey the torque values.  Do you not have ground wires/metal conduit?  Ground is for your protection only, not for the circuit to work.

Comment: If you'll edit to include the brand/model # of the dimmer you're looking at installing, someone will, I'm sure, look up the instructions for it to see if it's AL/CU rated.

Comment: Or use Al/Cu rated connectors to attach a Cu pigtail.

Answer (score 4):

## A qualified "Yes"

You'll need to look at the labeling for the specific dimmer you want to install to ensure that it says "CU/AL" or "AL/CU". These markings indicate that the connections on the switch are rated for aluminum wiring.

If it does *not* say that (or explicitly states that you should not use it on AL wiring), then return it and find one that does. This should be stated on the box the device comes in, so it should be easy to identify the right one at the store.

#### A note on AL wiring safety:

Once you've got an appropriate switch, make sure you tighten the screws down to the specified torque settings! If you do not, you could end up with a fire. This is what happened in the 1970s in the US which gave aluminum wiring its bad name. Properly torqued connections won't arc and cause a fire.

Since you have AL wiring in your house, it's worth investing in a torque screwdriver. I picked one up for ~$80 at my local big-box home improvement store. It's also worth investing in a set of ECX bits - I got a set that included a #1 and #2 size for about $5. Note that setting the proper torque with a Phillips, square drive or slotted driver will be *very* difficult because while all 3 will fit on an electrical device screw, none will hold very well at the torque levels needed (I found it difficult with a #2 square drive to properly torque to only 14 in/lbs without it slipping out).

Once you have the driver, you can spend a weekend shutting off a breaker and double checking the torque on every device (switch & receptacle) that is now without power. Do one breaker per weekend and reduce the chance of an electrical fire in your house!

Answer (score 2):

Do not just curl solid aluminum wire around the screw of a switch rated copper only and tighten. The connection will be OK at first but will gradualy loosen with time, and finally it will heat up and start arcing.

1. The most straightforward way to connect aluminum wiring to any device is to attach short lengths (~7 inches) of copper wire (called pigtails, usually solid copper rather than stranded) to the ends of the aluminum using approved connectors.  The other end of the copper pigtail is then connected to the device. Use #14 copper (or #12) to pigtail #12 aluminum (for 15  A circuits) and #12 copper to pigtail #10 aluminum (for 20 A circuits).

The best approved connector by far is the AlumiConn. Use the two port for pigtailing aluminum for switches. https://www.kinginnovation.com/en/products/Connections/Mechanical-Connectors

2. There are switches and receptacles designated CO/ALR which are approved for connecting aluminum wire under the screw just like copper. I installed some CO/ALR switches and wall receptacles in our house over 40 years ago and they are fine, but I still prefer pigtailing. Once you pigtail with copper you can change devices at any time with no special techniques.

I pigtailed the remainder of the aluminum wiring in our house with copper and those have also been trouble free. AlumiConns did not exist when I did this so I used standard twist on wire connectors which i packed with electrical antioxidant joint compound and these have worked with no failures.

The connection of switches is relatively undemanding compared to receptacles. If you are installing a special switch which has wire leads instead of screws, you could connect the aluminum house wire to the copper lead with standard wire nuts if you use antioxidant compound on the aluminum and know how to make the connection. Still of course it would be much safer to use a switch which specifies copper or aluminum.

Of course, it is much better to pigtail copper with AlumiConns. AlumiConns come with antioxidant grease in the ports so you do not have to purchase that separately. No prior abrading of the aluminum wire is necessary with AlumiConns.

AlumiConns "should be" tightened with a torque screwdriver (and I have one and use it), but there is (or used to be) a probably aceptable procedure for tightening AlumiConns on the solid aluminum wire: turn screw to contact the conductor then turn a certain approx fraction of a turn for #12 aluminum and a different fraction of a turn for #10 aluminum. This is a decent method of connection but does not guarantee the UL rating.

EDIT

If your special device has wire leads, then you could clamp the aluminum house wire in one port of a two port AlumiConn and clamp the wire lead to the device in the other port. You would not have to use an additional copper pigtail.